# Unix xml parsing

Tags: shell, unix

Below is the XML format . i want it to be formatted using unix shell scripting and output has been mentioned below . Thanks in advance .

```
<tbody><tr bgcolor=3D"#000000">=20
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Straight Through</font></=^M
b></td>
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Await Repair</font></b></=^M
td>
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Repaired await Verificati=^M
on</font></b></td>
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Reject await Verification=^M
</font></b></td>
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Repaired</font></b></td>
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Rejected</font></b></td>
      <td nowrap=3D""><b><font color=3D"#FFFFFF">Total</font></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align=3D"center">=20=20
      <td nowrap=3D"">211</td>

      <td nowrap=3D"">0</td>

      <td nowrap=3D"">0</td>

      <td nowrap=3D"">0</td>

      <td nowrap=3D"">7</td>

      <td nowrap=3D"">0</td>

      <td nowrap=3D"">218</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Output:

Straight Through,Await Repair,Repaired await Verification,Reject await Verification,Repaired,Rejected,Total
211,0,0,0,7,0,218

Comment: `echo Straigt...` :-)

Comment: We won't write code *for* you, but if you show us what you've tried and explain your problem we are happy to help out.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this could help you;

```
awk -v FS="(>|<)" '$0 ~ /font color/ {print $7}' yourXML | paste -s -d, - && awk -v FS="(>|<)" '$0 !~ /font color/ && $0 ~ /nowrap/ {print $3}' yourXML | paste -s -d, -
```

eg;

```
user@host $ awk -v FS="(>|<)" '$0 ~ /font color/ {print $7}' test | paste -s -d, - && awk -v FS="(>|<)" '$0 !~ /font color/ && $0 ~ /nowrap/ {print $3}' test | paste -s -d, -
Straight Through,Await Repair,Repaired await Verificati=^M,Reject await Verification=^M,Repaired,Rejected,Total
211,0,0,0,7,0,218
```